# Loop through a json file in correct order

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to looping through a json file to create a previous and next page.

So what I mean:

```
<a href="Link to next page">Next</a>
<a href="Link to previous page">Previous</a>
```

In place of the href there need to come a link to a product. This link is inside the JSON file.

```
{
    "collection": {
        "9409555": {
            "id": 9409555,
            "url": "lola-dress-9409555.html"
        },
        "9806609": {
            "id": 9806609,
            "url": "kimono-dress.html",
        }, //and 20 product more...
```

I'm struggeling what the best approach is to accomplish this. How do I determine on which "postion" in the loop I am and how do I determine what the next or previous value is.

Script

```
 $.getJSON('link-to-json-file/?format=json', function(data){
        $.each(data.products, function(key, product){
          console.log(key, product);
        });
      });
```

I know I can loop through a json object like above. Can anybody give me some directions what a good approach would be. Any help is more then welcome!

Comment: I edited your object literal. I only inserted spaces - it does not look complete, which can now readily be seen. If you are looking for position information inside a hash or object - it is not possible, there is no guaranteed order.

Answer (score 0):

According to your JSON structure you can do this:

```
  $.getJSON('link-to-json-file/?format=json', function(data){
    var pos = 0;
    for(var key in data.collection){
       console.log(pos);           
       console.log(key);
       console.log(data.collection[key].id);
       console.log(data.collection[key].url);
       pos++;
    });
  });
```

If your JSON has an array structure then you can use $.each

```
{
    "collection": [
        {
            "id": 9409555,
            "url": "lola-dress-9409555.html"
        },
        {
            "id": 9806609,
            "url": "kimono-dress.html",
        }
     ]
}

  $.getJSON('link-to-json-file/?format=json', function(data){
    $.each(data.callection, function(index, product){
      console.log(index); //this is the position 0, 1, 2 ...
      console.log(product);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Just as a note: While [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) also accepts objects `[...]If an object is used as the collection, the callback is passed a key-value pair each time[...]` the object should **not** contain a `length` property then `[...], if the collection has a property called length [...] the function might not work as expected.[...]`

Comment: The callback for `$.each(object, callback)` is `function(propertyName, value){}` not `function(index, value){}` as it is for arrays. Also most browsers will return the properties in alphabetical order, not the order they were declared in code.

Comment: That's right, but how can we know the position using each with and object?

Comment: The same way as you do with the `for ... in`: `var pos = 0; $.each(data.collection, function(propertyName, value){ pos++; });`.  Don't get me wrong, I don't want to suggest `$.each` with for object, because of the `length` _problem_. It is just a summary of the docs as the OP uses `$.each` with an object.

Answer (score 0):

This feels really hacky, but the only way I can think to do this is to loop through the object as you are doing and find the index of the product property (e.g. `"9806609": {`) in the raw `responseText`.

This very much assumes that it is formed in the way as you have posted it and there isn't other text in the `responseText` which could match. You could make it a little safer by stripping out new lines and spaces before and after colons etc.

```
// will store the final products
var products = [];

$.getJSON('link-to-json-file/?format=json', {}, function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
    // loop through object, adding the ID, product and position of "pid": in the jqXhr.responseText
    var sortProducts = [];
    $.each(data.collection, function(key, product){
        sortProducts.push({
            pid: key,
            product: product,
            pos: jqXhr.responseText.indexOf('"'+key+'":')
        });
    });

    // now sort the products by their position and store in the final array
    products = sortProducts.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.pos - b.pos;
    });
});
```

The you can find the index using a simple array search:

```
function findProductIndex(pid) {
    var prodIndex = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if(products[i].pid == pid) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

var idx = findProductIndex('9806609');
```

Of course if order is important to you, creating `collection` as an array is the way to go and you will have your sorted array straight away:

```
"collection": [
    {
        "id": 9409555,
        "url": "lola-dress-9409555.html"
    },
    {
        "id": 9806609,
        "url": "kimono-dress.html",
    }
]
```